# RabbitMQ - queue and dead lettering

Tags: php, rabbitmq, message-queue, dead-letter

I have set up a queue for sending emails.

Also, I have set up a dead-letter-exchange on this queue. Please see the below diagram.

[image]

As, you can see, the queue is Durable, has a TTL of 1 day and has a dead-letter-exchange set up for this queue.

What is happening is

1. When I push messages to this queue, and if there are no consumers listening, the messages get pushed to the DLX, but they should stay in the queue for 1 day as set by the TTL before going to the DLX.
2. If I send 100 messages to the queue, 99 go the DLX, 1 message is missed out somewhere. I don't know how is this happpening. Plese see the image below.
   [image]
3. I have set the queue as durable, still it gets deleted after messages go the DLX.
   [image]

Please help me with understanding what I might be missing.

Thanks

Comment: Your queue has the tag "Exp" which means "How long a queue can be unused for before it is automatically deleted (milliseconds).
(Sets the "x-expires" argument.)". At which value you set "Auto expire"?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot I am setting it to 86400*1000, which is 1 day.

Comment: @zaq178miami Never mind...figured it out. The code is too big to post here anyway.

Comment: It would be nice for other users if you post a solution to your question since you figured it out already